# Is Tomari-Te a valid type of Okinawan (Ryukyu) Kempo?

Tags: kempo, okinawa

[George Dillman](http://www.dillman.com/) claims to teach *Ryukyu* (Okinawan) *Kempo Tomari-te*. The theory here is that there were three villages teaching Kempo: *Naha*, *Shuri*, and *Tomari*. I have heard that *Tomari* really did not have its own form of *Kempo*, and George Dillman has simply used this but it is historically inaccurate. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each style of *Te* (or *Tii* or *Dii* in the Okinawan language) is named for the region from which it originated; in this case, the *Tomari* village, which is in the greater *Naha* region.

*Tomari-te* is not just a predecessor of Dillman's *Ryukyu Kempo*, but of *Shorinji-ryu*, *Motobu-ryu*, *Shorin(Matsubayashi)-ryu* and many others. Saying that Dillman teaches *Tomari-te* is a bit like saying that I teach *Iga-ryu Ninjutsu* – Some of the techniques in the *Bujinkan* may derive from the older *ryuha* but I was never trained explicitly in that. By that same token, Dillman's instruction traces back to Tomari-te by way of (from what I can determine):

(*Teruya Kishin* & *Sokyu Karyu*) -> *Matsumora Kousaku* -> (*Motobu Choki* & *Kyan Chotoku*) -> *Shimabuku Tatsuo* -> Harry G. Smith -> George Dillman

In all fairness, before he got all into the *Dim Mak* / *Kyushojutsu* stuff, Dillman was a [fairly respectable martial artist(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dillman) [***NB:*** Labeling someone as a fantasist seems to be pretty non-NPOV for wikipedia]. As far as I can determine, Dillman had no direct training in *Tomari-te*, and uses the name as a means of promoting his brand of *kempo* as something older.

Dillman aside, *Tomari-te* is acknowledged as a root of *Isshin-ryu*, and is noted as a root of *Motobu-ryu* in [McCarthy, Patrick and Yuriko (2002). "Motobu Teacher/Student Lineage Chart". Motobu Choki: Karate, My Art. Australia: International Ryukyu Karate Research Group. p.118.](http://www.koryu-uchinadi.com/index1.html)[aka *Watashi no Karate-jutsu*].

Comment: +1, very nuanced. I couldn't find the Tomari/Isshinryu link on McCarthy's site--do you mean because of the Motobu connection, or in its own right?

Comment: It seems that Wansu is considered by some to be a Tomari relic by way of Kyan, is this what you mean?

Comment: *Wanshu* is derived from Fujian White Crane, a part of *Naha-te*. The connection is, from what I understand, that *Motobu* and *Kyan* both had training in *Shuri-te*, *Naha-te*, and *Tomari-te*. The lineage for *Tomari-te* was as provided above.

Answer (score 3):

By all accounts that I've read, *Tomari-te* was indeed a distinct style, but over time (and proximity to *Shuri*) largely blended with the more popular *Shuri-te*.

Here is some information that might be helpful to you:
http://karatedo.hakuakai-matsubushidojo.com/tomarite.html

and: 
http://www.msisshinryu.com/history/tomari-te/

Comment: By the way, this is certainly not to say that Dillman's claims are genuine; there is a considerable controversy surrounding Dillman. I'm personally wary of anyone who claims to be a 10th dan in a traditional style without having a supported lineage.  (Contrast with, for example, Meitatsu Yagi, who has one degree of separation from Chojun Miyagi.)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Perhaps you could give a little more information about what behind the links is useful to the asker. Just a quick synopsis goes a long way. It may help to read about [how to answer questions here](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/171/answering-questions-on-martialarts-stackexchange-com)